# Extract Webdata from Microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I want to extract data from specific website into word
I have table containig hyperliks
[image: Word Table]

I want to extract some data from that link to next cell in word

Is it possible to copy html from   or  in front of 
sample weblink to page is [Google Patent Link](https://www.google.co.in/patents/US7884136B2?cl=en)

The div class=claim contains some images also.

I asked similar questions on other platforms but did not received answer. I Think it is not possible to copy text from web to word in HTML source formatting.

If anyone has any idea please suggest.